# enter/return/line break

Tags: support

Is there something I'm doing wrong? For the life of me everytime I post a question or answer, I can not figure out how to line break / return without the `<p>` tag. That's the only way to go to next line in the answer. Am I doing something wrong? or is this how it's supposed to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Paragraphs**

This:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>Praesent in metus diam.

Will produce this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
>
> Praesent in metus diam.

**Linebreaks**

This:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>Praesent in metus diam.

Will produce this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
> Praesent in metus diam.

---

Don't forget to check out our [Markdown editing help page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense... Thank You!!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I've just edited [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/159730/25936) of yours, check out its [revision history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/159730/revisions) to see my formatting edits.

Comment: haha that's cool!! any specific reason for using markdown? I've never seen it used before

Comment: It's mostly to avoid HTML (although a small subset of HTML is allowed). People usually can't resist the urge to try stupid stuff when they find a textarea that allows HTML.

Comment: oh ye that makes sense, a comment/reply box with HTML on becomes a 1 ton big kid sandbox lol I have to remember this in the future good to know!! thanks